# Smallest number evenly divisible by numbers 1 to 500

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I find smallest number evenly divisible by numbers 1 to 500?

Comment: Couldn't $1$ be a possible answer?

Comment: I think the asker clearly means the smallest number that has all integers between 1 and 500, inclusive, as divisors, Frank. That being said, Dorde, what have you tried? Any idea what to do? Are you in an advanced number theory course or a middle school student? We need context to be able to help you.

Comment: If you divide 1 by 500, you get 1/500=0.002. So that isn't whole number and 1 isn't evenly divisible by 500.

Comment: The Count - I'm doing some programming tasks, and I need to get answer of this to solve that problem

Comment: @Frank - I'm going with zero.

Comment: @joffan smartass :)  but I'm even assier $-500! < 0$ and $....< -3(500! < -2(500!) < -500! < 0.  So there is no smallest!  So ... let's assume the OP assumes the number is positive.

Comment: Well if you are programming...prod =1; for (n = 1 to 500){if (n is prime){q = 1; while (n^(q+1) le 500) {q++;} prod = prod*n^q;} return prod;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, using Python, the exact value seems to be

$73239622318952846593863874519042298829761338251289259046349190034596307420803713$

$39432775981989132698526831260664840887571331401331362333709431244066365980335206$

$1415560955398316253892220738945585450197206138869521568000$

---

Edit: Here's the code I used (as requested by Dorde):

```
def gcd(a,b):
    c,d=a,b
    while d>0:
        c,d = d, c%d
    return c

def lcm(a,b):
    return a*b//gcd(a,b)

lcm_1_to_500 = 1
for i in range(2,501):
    lcm_1_to_500 = lcm(lcm_1_to_500,i)
print(lcm_1_to_500)
```

Comment: Could you send me source code of program that calculates that?

Comment: @ĐorđeMilanović: I have edited the answer to include the code I used.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}$
You are looking for the least common multiple of the first $500$ numbers. That is, $\lcm (1,2,\dotsc,500)$. The problem of finding the $\lcm$ of the first $n$ numbers comes up in cryptography when implementing [Pollard's $p-1 $ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm).

There is an explanation of an algorithm to find the $\lcm$ of the first $n$ numbers on page 129 of the freely available text [*Elementary Number Theory* by William Stein](http://wstein.org/ent/). You can find the pdf on the linked page.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that, so how can i calculate lcm(1,2,…,500)?

Comment: @ĐorđeMilanović There is a detailed explanation of the algorithm and background information in the linked text. It also includes a reference implementation of the algorithm in Sage.

Comment: First you find all the prime factors of 1,2,..... 500.  Then you find out the highest power of each prime has in the numbers 1,2....500.  Or there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dotsc,500)$ is the product of $p^e$ for $p$ prime and $p^e$ the largest power of $p$ less than $500$.

Comment: A quick program tells us that this number is approximately equal to $7.3 \cdot 10^{217}$.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know, the Prime Number Theorem, in the version using Chebyshev's second function, says that $$ \operatorname{lcm} \{1,2,3, \cdots, 500 \} \approx e^{500} \approx 1.4 \cdot 10^{217}. $$
This is a bit low, given the answer by lhf. Not bad, though. Indeed, 
$$ \log \left( 7.3 \cdot 10^{217} \right) \approx 501.65  $$

> The second Chebyshev function is the logarithm of the least common
>   multiple of the integers from 1 to n.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Relationships

Comment: interesting, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compactly the number is $2^7\cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 499\#$

$499\#$ is [primorial $499$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) and the supplementary powers of the small primes make their multiplicity up to their highest power less than $500$.

Comment: right, $23^2 > 500$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}p^{\lfloor\log(500)/\log(p)\rfloor}=\\
\begin{align}
&7323962231895284659386387451904229882976133825128925904634919003459630\\
&7420803713394327759819891326985268312606648408875713314013313623337094\\
&3124406636598033520614155609553983162538922207389455854501972061388695\\
&21568000 = 7.323962231895\times10^{217}
\end{align}
$$